# Why does Imagemagick convert JPGs to larger image size than PNG?

Tags: imagemagick, image-conversion

I have a collection of textures for 3D design. Each folder of my collection contains the texture files (normal-map, colour-map, bump-map etc) and a preview file, like so:

[image: A single texture folder:]

Now I want to create icon files from the previews (to be displayed instead of the standard folder icon, to provide me with a quick overview)

I use imagemagick:

```
convert SOURCEFILE -background transparent -resize 256x256 -define icon:auto-resize="256,128,96,64,48,32,24,16" OUTPUTFILE
```

The basic result is as desired. But...

**Applied to a JPG, this line outputs a 256x256px icon (as desired).
However, applied to a PNG, the same line outputs a 128x128px icon.**

Can someone explain to me why this happens, and how to correct this?

Converting all PNG previews to JPGs first and then carrying out the conversion, is not so suitable as a workaround (the size is then correct, but there are issues with the background,resulting in blocky edges).

[image: Blocky edges after converting to JPG first]

Comment: I guess you should add your ImageMagick version number, at least for reference. `convert -version`.